# Ошибка в Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Какая здесь может быть ошибка в в строке с li draggable? (Как говорит консоль в браузере).

```
    <script>

    $("li").draggable({
        revert: true,
        scroll: false,
        helper: 'clone'
    });

    $("#city-second").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            this.value = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Нужно из приведенного списка городов, каждый из которых заключен в тег li, сделать так, чтобы их названия можно было перетаскивать в строку и строка, соответственно, заполнялась названиями этих городов.

Comment: А консоль в браузере так и говорит "Здесь какая-то ошибка"? Или что-то более конкретное?

Comment: jquery-ui.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6
    at jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
second-form.html?country=&city=&name=&login=&pass_confirmation=:51 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at second-form.html?country=&city=&name=&login=&pass_confirmation=:51

Подчеркивает строку с li: $("li").draggable({

Comment: `jQuery is not defined`, `$ is not defined` вы не подключили jQuery

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.drag-drop.plugin.js"></script>

Все подключено.

Comment: Это не jquery, а jquery-ui, плюгины без ядра)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде что-то вышло.) 
Только теперь он подчеркивает как ошибку вот это: .draggable({

Comment: Спасибо большое все вышло.)